# Selecting a single color from a matplotlib colormap in Juila

Tags: matplotlib, julia, colormap

I'm constructing a graph plot in Julia and need to color each edge of the graph differently, based on some weighting factor. I can't find a way to get a specific RGB (or HSV, it doesn't matter) value from a colormap. Let's say I'd like to get the RGB value on 'jet' that would correspond to a data value of `n` on  `imshow` plot.

In python, I would just use `jet(n)`, where `n` is the value along the colormap in which I am interested. PyPlot in Julia doesn't seem to have wrapped this functionality. I've also already tried indexing into the `cmap` object returned from `get_cmap()`. Any advice?

I'm stumped, so even an approximate solution would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can look at the `Colors.jl` package (https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Colors.jl):

```
using Colors
palette = colormap("Oranges", 100)
```

Then you can access each color with `palette[n]`. Or are you using `PyCall`? A code describing what you're trying to do would help.

Comment: Could sombody please tell me how to use the palette defined above in a simple command just like `plot(randn(10), "o")` under PyPlot?